# Swift how do I populate my tableView after receiving data from API

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am currently working on a project that uses a company's API and populate my tableView with those data. However, my program works by having the user to search for the information through in game names and then the data will be displayed after a click on the  "search" button

The problem I am facing with is that my 3 tableView functions

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

all loads when the app loads instead of AFTER the user's call to pull the information through the API

I was thinking if swift can do a function within a function but Xcode gives me an error of does not conform to protocol error

Is there anyway I can make the tableView load AFTER my user's have clicked the search button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have guaranteed that you have the data run the method

`tableView.reloadData()`

This will refresh the table view and load any new data in it.